How does Unity save data in PlayerPrefs?
I want to read data from the registry in my standalone WPF application, which is created inside a game on Unity using PlayerPrefs. The question is how to read and write float to the registry as DWORD32.
public static float Int64ToFloat(long value)
{
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
    byte[] floatBytes = new byte[4];
        
    Array.Copy(bytes, floatBytes, 4);

    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                Array.Reverse(floatBytes);

    float floatValue = BitConverter.ToSingle(floatBytes, 0);

    return floatValue;
}

This code returns extremely small values, such as 1.35E-43.

Have you used regedit to look at the stored value? It could be that Unity doesn't use a standard encoding for float values.

@MaxPlay Yes, I looked at the values in the registry, but to be honest it didn't help me much as I've never worked with this kind of coding, so it's hard to tell what it is by eye. If I had access to the sources of the PlayerPrefs class, it would be much easier.

Unity does not save a float but rather a double! It is indeed quite a hack but if you look closely you will find that your DWORD (32bit) contains indeed a 64-bit long! (no clue why they didn't properly go for QWORD or directly binary there)
As mentioned already for floating point types you can't simply cut the bytes and expect the value to remain the same as you could do with long -> int.
You can simply use
// Have in mind that the key here is NOT the one you use in Unity but also contains a certain trailing hash string
public static float GetFloat(string key, float fallback = 0f)
{
    using (RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Unity\UnityEditor\" + Application.companyName + "\\" + Application.productName))
    {
        var value = registryKey?.GetValue(key);
        if (value is long longValue)
        {                      
            // Convert the 64-bit value to a double
            var doubleValue = BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(longValue);
            // then simply cast to cut its precision down
            var floatValue = (float)doubleValue;
            return floatValue;
        }
    }

    return fallback;
}

For you to verify
var input = 12345678901234567890.1234567890f;
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("TestFloat", input);
var output = GetFloat("TestFloat_h1435782019");
Assert.AreApproximatelyEqual(input,output, "Value retrieved from registry does not match the value stored in PlayerPrefs.");


I just also stumbled over this snippet
If we can trust it the hash string is basically calculated as

public class PlayerPrefsHash
{
  // Returns the string property name Unity would generate for a player prefs registry key value 
  // e.g., "PlayerGold" -> "PlayerGold_hXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  public static string Hash(string name)
  {
    uint hash = 5381;
    foreach (char c in name)
      hash = hash * 33 ^ c;
    string key = name + "_h" + hash;
    return key;
  }
}


So you could use this in my method above and be able to use the same key constant on Unity as in WPF side.
And at least in my quick test it seams to be accurate
var key = PlayerPrefsHash.Hash("TestFloat");
Assert.AreEqual("TestFloat_h1435782019", key, "PlayerPrefsHash.Hash does not match PlayerPrefs generated hash.");


The representation methods for integer types and floating point numbers are different.
Let's take an example
Integer types can be converted to intuitive binary format as follows:
integer 11 = 00001011
but.
Floating-point representation is slightly different.
Let's take an 8-bit number as an example.
01011111
The first 4 digits of this number represent an integer
0101 = 5
The last 4 digits are calculated as follows:
1111 = 0.5 + 0.25 + 0.125 + 0.0625
Each digit represents 2 to the -n power.
If you want to cut off part of the long type and use it as an integer, and use the latter number as a decimal and store it in the float type, there is also the following method.
int n = 17012165
float f = n / 10000 // 1701.2165f


Floats are representated a lot diffrernt than ints.
Ints are stored in 32 bits, where, from right to left, each bit stores a higher number
(0110) => 03+2²+2¹+0⁰ where 0⁰ = 0 evaluates to 6.
Floats are stored using sign, exponent and fraction, where the first bit is the sign (0 = positive, 1 = negative), the next 8 bits is the exponent and this is like int but at the end it is ^(-127) (at least in IEEE752) and the fraction starts with the first value counting either 0 or 2 ^(-1), the next ^(-2) and so on until ^(-23). At last everything is calculated together:
EXP^(-127) × (1+FRAC

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
